# Login screen remains grey after successful login

Tags: gdm, 21.04

I'm using Gnome vanilla. Many times, after I login, instead of getting the normal Gnome shell desktop I get a grey screen. It's like the GDM greeter but without any controls whatsoever.

<strike>When this happens I open a virtual terminal and reboot.</strike>

**Edit:** I found out that if I go to any virtual terminal and then return to tty1, I'm presented with the login screen again and usually when I login the second time, I get to the gnome session.

How do I discover what is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the grey screen after a fresh boot or after resuming? 

Comment: After fresh boot.